# Is there a well-ordered uncountable set of real numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, real-numbers, well-orders

**[The Problem and its Solution](http://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Eelkies/Misc/sol6.html)**

**My approach (in a different way):** We write $\mathbb{R}=\displaystyle\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} [n-1,n]$ and let us call $[n-1,n]=I_n$.

Suppose $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ is uncountable and is well-ordered. Then, at least one of $I_n$'s, say $I_k$ will contain uncountably many elements of $S$.

$A=I_k \cap S$ is bounded and uncountable $\implies$
There exists at least one strictly monotone decreasing sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $A$ which converges to $p$ (say) [Justification of the claim below]. $\{x_n\} \subset S$ has no least element, since if $m= \displaystyle \min_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \{x_n\}=x_k$, we have $x_{k+1}<x_k=m$, a contradiction.

Thus, there is no such $S \subset \mathbb{R}$.

**Justification:**

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3569035/389992

Is the procedure correct?

Kindly **VERIFY**

Comment: How do you know that you can choose distinct $p_x$ for all $x\in A$? Unless you can justify that, your argument is circular.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, I've updated my answer by adding a link to a proof of the very statement I was trying to justify. Is my argument correct now?

Comment: Yes, with that argument such a proof will work.